Using TexLive in NixOS via shell.nix
I am trying to build PDF files using R Markdown in NixOS.  I've built this file successfully in Ubuntu but would prefer to get this working on NixOS, specifically through a shell.nix file.
$ R -e "rmarkdown::render('lab.rmd')"
R version 4.3.3 (2024-02-29) -- "Angel Food Cake"
Copyright (C) 2024 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

> rmarkdown::render('lab.rmd')


processing file: lab.rmd
                                                                                                               
output file: lab.knit.md

/nix/store/kn7z7q9657y376qpd65b3ln5nykx69kb-pandoc-cli-3.1.11.1/bin/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS lab.knit.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash --output lab.tex --lua-filter /home/averdow/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/rmarkdown/rmarkdown/lua/pagebreak.lua --lua-filter /home/averdow/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/rmarkdown/rmarkdown/lua/latex-div.lua --embed-resources --standalone --highlight-style tango --pdf-engine xelatex --variable graphics --variable 'geometry:margin=1in' 
! Could not start dynamically linked executable: xelatex

! NixOS cannot run dynamically linked executables intended for generic

! linux environments out of the box. For more information, see:

! https://nix.dev/permalink/stub-ld

Error: LaTeX failed to compile lab.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See lab.log for more info.
In addition: Warning message:
In system2(..., stdout = if (use_file_stdout()) f1 else FALSE, stderr = f2) :
  error in running command
Execution halted

I've looked at the stub-ld link but I haven't been able to make a working shell.nix with the options listed there.
This is my shell.nix for this project:
{ pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {}
}:

pkgs.rstudioWrapper.override {
  packages = with pkgs.rPackages; [ 
    magick 
    tesseract 
    dplyr 
    pander 
    purrr 
    tidyverse 
    svglite 
    yaml 
    df2yaml 
    # tinytex
  ] ++ [ 
    pkgs.pandoc 
    pkgs.texliveFull
  ];
}

I have tlmgr disabled when using the nix packages via .Rprofile:
options(tinytex.install_packages = FALSE)
options(tinytex.tlmgr_update = FALSE)

xelatex seems to work from command line:
$ xelatex
This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999995 (TeX Live 2023/nixos.org) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
**
CTRL-D
! End of file on the terminal... why?

Any ideas on how to get this working using the existing Nix packages?  I'm currently testing a shell script that runs the tex live installer but I would prefer a cleaner solution.
Some workarounds I've tried:

Adding nix-ld into shell.nix: could not get a valid format
tinytex R package: runs into same ld issue
latex: can't handle unicode
Ubuntu: works but not preferred
Manual install of TexLive: clunky and possibly overkill, not sure if it works yet

Tried a flake.nix, got the same results:
{
  description = "RStudio with custom R packages and additional tools";

  inputs = {
    nixpkgs.url = "github:NixOS/nixpkgs";
  };

  outputs = { self, nixpkgs }:
    let
      system = "x86_64-linux";
      pkgs = import nixpkgs { inherit system; };
    in
    {
      defaultPackage.x86_64-linux = pkgs.rstudioWrapper.override {
        packages = with pkgs.rPackages; [
          magick
          tesseract
          dplyr
          pander
          purrr
          tidyverse
          svglite
          yaml
          df2yaml
        ] ++ [
          pkgs.pandoc
          pkgs.texliveFull
        ];
      };
    };
}


Which version of nixpkgs are you targeting? (If you were using a flake instead of a simple shell.nix, we'd already know that).

...and bigger picture, do you know where the xelatex binary is coming from? (Is it in fact coming from the Nix store, or is something elsewhere in your PATH overriding it?)

@CharlesDuffy I am using nixpkgs 24.05.  The xelatex binary is coming from texliveFull, specifically /nix/store/qx8hspng24wnpw21gv2317c8ff2gknv1-texlive-2023-env/bin/xelatex  (Before shell.nix is loaded which xelatex returns an error.)

I also tried a flake.nix and got the same results, added to original question.

Your flake.nix isn't pinning a specific rev, so there's no guarantee that anyone else who runs it gets a flake.lock pointed at the same place. (I suppose "if you were using a flake, we'd already know" assumes either a specific pin or the flake.lock being distributed).
